# Selenium Python Finding text in row and click on onlcik button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to click on a `onclick` button that contain a specific word on the same row. Try to play with `ancestror` and sibling but was not successful.

```
#WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//td[contains(text()='PE49081')]//following::td[1]/img']"))).click()
```

The table i am working on is the following :

```
 <table class="corpsTable" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
        <tbody><tr class="bginterfaces">              
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Version</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Type mine</div></td>
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Apsad</div></td>              
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Sra</div></td>              
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Nbr place</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">P.F</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Code auto</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">P.R</div></td>             
        </tr>
                    <tr class="detailsCorps">           
            <td nowrap="nowrap">
                
          <img src="test2_files/affecter.png" alt="Affecter le vÃ©hicule" title="Affecter le vÃ©hicule" onclick="AffeMarque(0,'','','&amp;Code_Vers=76768')" width="16" height="16" border="0">                      
                      </td>             
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;DDMYO</td>
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                       9A
                        </td>
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">27A</div></td>              
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">5</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">4</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;PE4901</td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center"></div></td>             
                      </tr><tr class="detailsCorps">            
            <td nowrap="nowrap">
                
          <img src="test2_files/affecter.png" alt="Affecter le vÃ©hicule" title="Affecter le vÃ©hicule" onclick="AffeMarque(0,'','','&amp;Code_Vers=96165')" width="16" height="16" border="0">                      
                      </td>             
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;1.2 PURE TECH 110 ACTIVE</td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;CUHNZ6S</td>
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                       13C
                        </td>
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">31I</div></td>              
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">5</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">5</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;PE49074</td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">110</div></td>             
                      </tr><tr class="detailsCorps">            
            <td nowrap="nowrap">
                
          <img src="test2_files/affecter.png" alt="Affecter le vÃ©hicule" title="Affecter le vÃ©hicule" onclick="AffeMarque(0,'','','&amp;Code_Vers=89178')" width="16" height="16" border="0">                      
                      </td>             
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;1.2 PURE TECH 110 ALLURE</td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;CUHNZ6S</td>
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                       13C
                        </td>
          <td colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">31J</div></td>              
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">5</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">5</div></td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;PE49039</td>
          <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">110</div></td>             
                      </tr><tr class="detailsCorps">            
            <td nowrap="nowrap">
```

I am trying to  find for example the row that contain the number PE49081 and click on the img on the same row.

thanks for youe help

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right, but only thing you did wrong was to look for `following-sibling` when in real it's the parent first and then `descendant`

probably using this xpath, should solve your issue  :

```
//td[contains(text(), 'PE49039')]/../descendant::img
```

and in code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10 ).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//td[contains(text(), 'PE49039')]/../descendant::img"))).click()
```

Comment: Great ! Was it helpful ?if yes, can you accept this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this. –